# Unity: Repeating a texture over a plane depending on it's scale

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures

I've managed to do this with a cube by using the following [script](https://github.com/Dsphar/Cube_Texture_Auto_Repeat_Unity/blob/master). I tried adapting the script to a plane, although it seems difficult.

The most obvious change is to use `PrimitiveType.Plane` instead of `PrimitiveType.Cube` inside of the `CheckForDefaultSize()` function. When trying this out, the texture is just broken all over the plane. I'm suspecting the issue comes up when setting the UVs, although I have no idea of how to fix this.

The cube's UVs:

```
    //Front
    meshUVs[0] = new Vector2(0, 0);
    meshUVs[1] = new Vector2(width, 0);
    meshUVs[2] = new Vector2(0, height);
    meshUVs[3] = new Vector2(width, height);

    //Back
    meshUVs[4] = new Vector2(0, 0);
    meshUVs[5] = new Vector2(width, 0);
    meshUVs[6] = new Vector2(0, height);
    meshUVs[7] = new Vector2(width, height);

    //Left
    meshUVs[8] = new Vector2(0, 0);
    meshUVs[9] = new Vector2(width, 0);
    meshUVs[10] = new Vector2(0, height);
    meshUVs[11] = new Vector2(width, height);

    //Right
    meshUVs[12] = new Vector2(0, 0);
    meshUVs[13] = new Vector2(width, 0);
    meshUVs[14] = new Vector2(0, height);
    meshUVs[15] = new Vector2(width, height);
```

Here's how the original script looks on a cube:

1x1x1 scale
[image: Cube with scale 1]

3x1x1~ish scale
[image: The same cube scaled 3 times over the x axis, the texture is now repeated thrice]

Comment: But that is repeating it 3x. Its just upside down

Comment: @BugFinder It's working as intended on a cube, not a plane, the screenshots may be a bit misleading since it's top-down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to do this is to use a Quad instead. [A plane is divided into 200 triangles, while quads only have 2.](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PrimitiveObjects.html) That's why I was having issues setting the UVs.

To make it work, you just have to change `SetupUvMap` and `CheckForDefaultSize`:

```
private Vector2[] SetupUvMap(Vector2[] meshUVs)
{
    var width = _currentScale.x;
    var height = _currentScale.y;

    meshUVs[0] = new Vector2(0, 0);
    meshUVs[1] = new Vector2(width, 0);
    meshUVs[2] = new Vector2(0, height);
    meshUVs[3] = new Vector2(width, height);

    return meshUVs;
}

private bool CheckForDefaultSize()
{
    if (_currentScale != Vector3.one) return false;

    var quad = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Quad);

    DestroyImmediate(GetComponent<MeshFilter>());
    gameObject.AddComponent<MeshFilter>();
    GetComponent<MeshFilter>().sharedMesh = quad.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().sharedMesh;

    DestroyImmediate(quad);

    return true;
}
```

Although I did stop using the `CheckForDefaultSize` function altogether in my case.